PostgreSQL Case with a subquery using a different where clause
I am trying to query the correct price by going through and choosing between 2 prices.
These are in order of importance from highest to lowest:

if [tran_type] is equal to Quot than choose this price
if [default_level] is greater than 0, going to be a number from 1-8

The [default_level] is a place holder with a numerical value which is used to signify a pricing level from 1 to 8.
The price when [default_level] is greater than 0 is stored as the blank [start_cust_or_group] in the same table and [level_] is the value it is tied with for the 1-8 pricing level.
So say if [default_level] is 6 then the correct price I need pulled is for [start_cust_or_group] to equal blank [level_] would be 6 and the latest date available [start_date]



item_or_pricecode
uom_code
tran_type
default_level
level_
price




27MIETE11K
EA

6
0
0.00


22RGRD45BS
CT
Quot

0
144.10



Below is what I would like the final outcome to be.
For the first item (27MIETE11K) it sees tran_type was blank then it moved on and found default_level was 6 so it chooses Level_ where its 6 and start_cust_or_group is blank and it takes that price. For the next item (22RGRD45BS) it sees tran_type is Quot so it populates the price in the LevelResult. This part of the query with Quot works.



item_or_pricecode
uom_code
LevelResult




27MIETE11K
EA
29.57


22RGRD45BS
CT
144.10



SELECT 
    [item_or_pricecode], [uom_code], 
    CASE 
        WHEN [tran_type] <> '' THEN [price] 
        WHEN [default_level] > 0 THEN XXXXXX
        ELSE 0 
    END AS LevelResult 
FROM
    [test].[tablepricing].[pricing] 
WHERE 
    [start_cust_or_group] = '7000192' 
    AND [cust_shipto_num] = '2' 
    AND [RowDeleted] = 0 
ORDER BY 
    [start_date] DESC

That code works if I put [default_level] but that just returns the value for default_level in the LevelResult column.
I need to have a select query where I put XXXXXX. I don't know how to pass the [default_level] to the select query to match with the [level_] or if it's even possible.
SELECT 
    x.[item_or_pricecode], x.[uom_code], x.[level_], x.[price],x.[start_date]
FROM 
    (SELECT
         x.[item_or_pricecode], x.[uom_code], x.[level_], x.[price],x.[start_date],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x.[item_or_pricecode] ORDER BY x.[start_date] DESC, x.[level_] ASC) AS rn
     FROM 
         [test].[tablepricing].[pricing] AS x
     WHERE
         [start_cust_or_group] = '' 
         AND [RowDeleted] = 0  
         AND [item_or_pricecode] = '27MIETE11K') AS x 
WHERE 
    x.rn <= 8




item_or_pricecode
uom_code
level_
price
start_date




27MIETE11K
EA
1
38.65
2024-01-15


27MIETE11K
EA
2
34.81
2024-01-15


27MIETE11K
EA
3
33.05
2024-01-15


27MIETE11K
EA
4
31.43
2024-01-15


27MIETE11K
EA
5
30.49
2024-01-15


27MIETE11K
EA
6
29.57
2024-01-15


27MIETE11K
EA
7
28.97
2024-01-15


27MIETE11K
EA
8
28.39
2024-01-15



This is a separate query to show the level prices and how I got it to find the latest date for each entry.
Normally if I just did
WHERE item_or_pricecode = '27MIETE11K' 
  AND start_cust_or_group = ''

on the pricing table I would get 78 entries with older prices mixed in.

Piece of advice: if you have nested queries (like in your second query), I'd recommend not to use the same alias (here: x) in the inner and outer scope. That makes for really difficult and confusing reading of your code, and can lead to very unexpected and hard to diagnose problems at times. Use something useful, meaningful, and use a different alias for each level in your query

You wrtite ORDER BY x.[start_date] DESC - what is this column? pls, add to data source example. Also about [start_cust_or_group] = ''

it won't fit i had to remove rows because it spills over to the next line on the forum so I can't  the [start_date] column is formatted just like 2024-05-28 00:00:00.000

Please tag the RDBMS you are using... they all have a different SQL dialect

oh sorry there you go

Do you have 1 table pricing or more? Please show table (tables), data example and desired output.

i did that's those 2 tables at the top i'm not gonna put the whole table cause there are like 50 columns that aren't needed. it's just one table [test].[tablepricing].[pricing]

Don't need all columns. First table1(item_or_pricecode, uom_code, tran_type, default_level, level_?, price) and second table2 (item_or_pricecode, uom_code, level_, price, start_date).

that 3rd table at the bottom is just to show how I got the correct pricing out of the table for the levels 1-8 , the first table is the data I have to decide which price is chosen and the 2nd table is what I would like the output to be. it might be confusing because the level pricing is stored on the same table as the rest of the customers pricing it's just the level pricing is stored under a BLANK customer.

This has a variation posted by the same OP at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79270038/postgresql-find-a-price-going-through-multiple-cases, so is a duplicate.

This question is similar to: PostgreSQL find a price going through multiple cases. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
